# c++ portable way to get time since application started?

Tags: c++, datetime

In c++, what's a good portable way (maybe using some library) to get the time since the application started, with al least sub-millisecond accuracy?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Since sub-millisecond is not possible on all platforms, then what could be the way to get it with the most possible accuracy?

Comment: You'll not likely find such a thing, because "sub-millisecond" is better than the best resolution you can get on at least one major platform (Windows). Other than that, you should be able to do such a thing in a simple wrapper class around `GetProcessTimes` (Windows) and `times` (POSIX).

Comment: Sub-millisecond is going to be platform dependent. There's a LOT of coverage of this on SO if you search.

Answer (score 2):

[Boost Date Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/date_time.html) can help but as Damon already noted in a comment, this is fairly platform-dependent question, and your minimum requirement is harsher than what the most widely uses OS can support.

Hence, an abstraction as provided by [Boost](http://www.boost.org) is helpful.   There of course countless other libraries, but the [Boost Date Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/date_time.html) library has *an option for nano-second resolution* where available, but you need to enable it at build-time:

> ## Compilation Options
>
> By default the
>   posix_time system uses a single 64 bit
>   integer internally to provide a
>   microsecond level resolution. As an
>   alternative, a combination of a 64 bit
>   integer and a 32 bit integer (96 bit
>   resolution) can be used to provide
>   nano-second level resolutions. The
>   default implementation may provide
>   better performance and more compact
>   memory usage for many applications
>   that do not require nano-second
>   resolutions.
>
> To use the alternate resolution (96
>   bit nanosecond) the variable
>   BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG
>   must be defined in the library users
>   project files (ie Makefile, Jamfile,
>   etc). This macro is not used by the
>   Gregorian system and therefore has no
>   effect when building the library.

Comment: I'm looking at [Boost's posix_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) but can't find out how to get the time since the application started.

Comment: Did you see the section 'Construct from Clock' ?

Comment: Yes, It all says "gets the local/current time". But can't find out how to get the time since the app started.

Comment: Same with all the other (simpler) time functions: first make one call at the start and assign to a variable 't1'; later when  when you want to measure this assign again to another variable 't2'. The difference between t1 and t2 (which Boost will compute for you eg via time_period) is the time spent.  If you actually want to analyse system load etc then you need OS-specific functions, see e.g. GNU acct for that on Unix.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `clock_t clock ( void );` included from `time.h`. It returns the number of clock ticks elapsed since the program was launched.

Have a look at [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/) for more information.